# Setting selenium webdriver proxy after browsing some pages

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hello Selenium experts,

I am using c# webdriver and setting proxy as shown below. But language does not matter.

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        proxy.Kind = ProxyKind.Manual;
        proxy.IsAutoDetect = false;
        proxy.SslProxy = "127.0.0.1:40001";
        options.Proxy = proxy;
        options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");    
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I wanted to set the proxy after browsing some URL. Is it possible to set proxy later instead of setting it during initialization time?

The use case is that my proxy records traffic and  I don't want to record the login pages, I want to record requests after user logs-in to the application. Let me know if there are other ways to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you add a Java tag?

Comment: Stack overflow suggestion. Removed.